# get description from another data frame with code column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[101, 'DC1', 'QA,DEMO'],
               [101, 'EM5', 'QA,DEMO'],
               [102, 'RA6', 'PA,QA,GF'],
               [103, 'DC1', 'AB,LK'],
               [103, 'RA6', 'OO'],
               [103, 'PA4', 'AB,OO']
              ]
              , columns=['Call_id', 'Agent_id', 'Task_code'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['QA', 'Enter phone number'],
               ['DEMO', 'ASK EMAIL ID'],
               ['PA', 'make notes'],
               ['GF', 'take call back'],
               ['AB', 'Apply bell mark'],
               ['LK', 'call Low markets'],
               ['OO','Out of order']
              ]
              , columns=['Task_code', 'Task_Desc'])
```

output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[101, 'DC1', 'QA,DEMO','Enter phone number and ASK EMAIL ID'],
               [101, 'EM5', 'QA,DEMO','Enter phone number and ASK EMAIL ID'],
               [102, 'RA6', 'PA,QA,GF','make notes and Enter phone number and take call back'],
               [103, 'DC1', 'AB,LK','Apply bell mark and call Low markets'],
               [103, 'RA6', 'OO','Out of order'],
               [103, 'PA4', 'AB,OO','Apply bell mark and Out of order']
              ]
              , columns=['Call_id', 'Agent_id', 'Task_code','Task_desc'])
```

I want to merge the TASK_desc with 'and' on df1 for each agent id and call_id in Python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task_mapper = dict(zip(df2["Task_code"],df2["Task_Desc"]))

def get_description(values):

    values = values.strip().split(",")
    values = list(filter(None,values))
    descriptions = [task_mapper.get(value,"") for value in values]
    return " and ".join(descriptions)

df1["Task_desc"] = df1["Task_code"].apply(get_description)

print(df1) # your output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary for mapping splitted values by `,` and then join values by `and` separator:

```
d = df2.set_index('Task_code')['Task_Desc']

f = lambda x:  ' and '.join(d.get(y) for y in x.split(',') if y in d)

df1['Task_Desc'] = df1['Task_code'].apply(f)
print (df1)
   Call_id Agent_id Task_code  \
0      101      DC1   QA,DEMO   
1      101      EM5   QA,DEMO   
2      102      RA6  PA,QA,GF   
3      103      DC1     AB,LK   
4      103      RA6        OO   
5      103      PA4     AB,OO   

                                           Task_Desc  
0                Enter phone number and ASK EMAIL ID  
1                Enter phone number and ASK EMAIL ID  
2  make notes and Enter phone number and take cal...  
3               Apply bell mark and call Low markets  
4                                       Out of order  
5                   Apply bell mark and Out of order
```

Or us pandas functions for explode column, merging and aggregate `join` with different separators:

```
f1 = lambda x: ' and '.join(x.unique())
f2 = lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())
df = (df1.assign(Task_code = df1['Task_code'].str.split(','))
         .explode('Task_code')
         .merge(df2, on='Task_code')
         .groupby(['Call_id','Agent_id'])
         .agg({'Task_code':f2, 'Task_Desc':f1})
         .reset_index())
print (df)
   Call_id Agent_id Task_code  \
0      101      DC1   QA,DEMO   
1      101      EM5   QA,DEMO   
2      102      RA6  QA,PA,GF   
3      103      DC1     AB,LK   
4      103      PA4     AB,OO   
5      103      RA6        OO   

                                           Task_Desc  
0                Enter phone number and ASK EMAIL ID  
1                Enter phone number and ASK EMAIL ID  
2  Enter phone number and make notes and take cal...  
3               Apply bell mark and call Low markets  
4                   Apply bell mark and Out of order  
5                                       Out of order
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my way:
split into list

```
df1['desc'] = df1.Task_code.str.split(',')
```

make dictionary  for lookup

```
dictionary = dict(zip(df2.Task_code,df2.Task_Desc))
def descdic(l):
    return ' and '.join([dictionary[i] for i in l])
```

apply to data

```
df1.desc = df1.desc.apply(lambda x: descdic(x))
```